# How do I add an event listener to a dynamically created HTMLcollection?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am creating a small library app and I am trying to add a delete entry function. I am looking to add the actual functionality of the button but I can't figure out how to add the eventlistener to each instance. When I click on the image it does nothing.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
//dynamic creation of trash button
let deleteEntry = document.createElement("td")
const deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
const deleteImg = document.createAttribute("type");

deleteImg.value = "image";
deleteBtn.className = "deletebtn"
deleteBtn.src = "red_trash_can.png";
deleteEntry.append(deleteBtn);
deleteBtn.setAttributeNode(deleteImg)
    
//
const trashBtn = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("deletebtn"));
    
trashBtn.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click',e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```html
<td>
   <input class="deletebtn" src="red_trash_can.png" type="image">
</td>
```

Comment: I think this is the problem ''getElementsByClassName''. Use 'querySelectorAll' instead.

Comment: @Irfanwani when i use "querySelectorAll" it still gives me an empty array

Comment: That's because document.getElementsByClassName("deletebtn") or querySelectorAll gets called only once, when the DOM is loaded. It doesn't bind dynamically added elements. I'm having the same issue with VanillaJS, but if you're using jQuery, you can easily do `$(document).on('click', '.deletebtn', () => {...})`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event listener directly to the `deleteBtn` before appending it. And also the `type` can be added directly like you do with the `className` or the `src`.

**Working example:** (*i used a dummy image and a simple string in `console.log()` because the event took so long*)

```js
//dynamic creation of trash button
const deleteEntry = document.createElement("td")
const deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");

deleteBtn.type = "image";
deleteBtn.className = "deletebtn"
deleteBtn.src = "https://picsum.photos/200";
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("You clicked the image!")
});

deleteEntry.append(deleteBtn);
document.querySelector("#wrapper").append(deleteEntry);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```